# Google geocoding fails but address exists when entered into google maps web page

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I'm doing geocoding for our web app with google api and getting a 602 error but when i put the address into the google maps search it finds the location perfectly.  this seems to happen less than 5% of the time. anybody else come across this?

the url i'm using for the geocoding is this

http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=1062+N.+main+st,bowling+green,OH+43402&output=csv&key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

If you go to maps.google.com and put this address in, its finds it perfectly.

1062+N.+main+st,bowling+green,OH+43402

Answer (score 0):

The zip code is not part of that record in the geocoder, if you remove it, the geocoder can resolve the address:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=1062%20N%20Main%20St,Bowling%20Green,OH&geocode=1